# Menu not Showing on Mobile or While the page is shrinked

Tags: menus

I just did a website with WordPress with `idolcorp` theme, but I noticed the menu are not showing at all on mobile devices or when I shrink the page size.

The Page URL is www.ariss.com.ng

Answer (score 0):

I can't see the style.css file of this theme. But through browser I indicate, media rules (at line#4884 of style.css) for .menu-top-menu-container cause this behavior.
Removing .menu-top-menu-container's property from this media rules could fix your problem.